# Format while typing EXCEL/VBA

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

After some search i camed arround with Siddharth Rout code for formatting the textbox while typing , but for no apparently reason it gives me a bad format or na infinite one.

```
Dim CursorPosition As Long
Dim boolSkip As Boolean
Dim countCheck As Long

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
'~~> This avoids refiring of the event
If boolSkip = True Then
    boolSkip = False
    Exit Sub
End If

'~~> Get current cursor postion
CursorPosition = TextBox1.SelStart
boolSkip = True

'~~> Format the text
TextBox1.Text = Format(TextBox1.Text, "###-###.###-###")

'~~> Re-position the cursor
If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ".") - 1 > 0 Then _
TextBox1.SelStart = InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ".") - 1
End Sub
```

The ideia is that the user types something like "123456789852" , 12-numbers and it formats to "123-456.789-852" while typing as it's easier to spot any input mistake.

Kind Regards

Comment: First you need the KeyPress event to only take numbers. Second when you change the text from the Sub, I think you may be better to append `-` and `.` depends on the length that's been typed and changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any other answer would fail you could try this very ugly solution:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If Len(TextBox1.Text) = 3 And TextBox1.Text Like "###" = True Then TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "-"
If Len(TextBox1.Text) = 7 And TextBox1.Text Like "###-###" = True Then TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "."
If Len(TextBox1.Text) = 11 And TextBox1.Text Like "###-###.###" = True Then TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "-"
If Len(TextBox1.Text) > 15 Then TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, 15)

End Sub
```